# Correct word for work vacant, place, employment

Tags: single-word-requests

In Human Resources, we want to implement MOF (Manual of Functions) for each employee based on their area and position, so that when an employee leaves, the functions remains for the next employee. We now lack of a word to name this in HR.

What is the best word to describe the position (that is, job title) of an employee in a specific area of an organization?

Can anyone please help suggest a word? Possible candidates I found are *vacant*, *place*, *employment*, and *job*.

Comment: I would suggest 'vacant'. But you may like to note that "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" is "out of scope for this site". See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so your question may be closed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes".

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks for feedback and sorry for not reading the Help Center.

Comment: How about'post'. The postholder (individual employee) may change but the post (role) remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

The *functions and tasks* of an incumbent employee comprise that employee's **role**.

Should an employee vacate the position, that **role** remains, though the *functions and tasks* must be shared amongst remaining employees until a new incumbent can be hired.

From time to time a single employee may occupy two roles simultaneously. When in a meeting the perspective of those two roles on an issue differs, the incumbent might refer to *switching hats now* so that the audience can note that the other role will is now speaking to the matter.